# Apache and .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just moved from a standard shared server to a centOS5.5 with Apache- I'm also new to using Apache.

My previous shared host .htaccess file had the following contents;

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?_url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

What are the steps in adding the above to use with Apache? ie: what console commands, what file must be opened and do I place all of the above from my htaccess file there?

Thanks!

Comment: That would definitely help http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
As a quick and not-guaranteed-to-work solution you could just place this file into your website root.

Comment: @J0HN: Thank you but the redirects don't work even with the .htaccess file in the web root

Comment: Maybe you have mod_rewrite disabled?
Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007041/change-url-in-codeigniter/7007124#7007124 there are some instructions

Answer (score 1):

The above is an Apache .htaccess file  - you should be fine by simply placing it in your new web root.

Comment: Thanks- but the redirects don't work :( file is placed in my root (/home/user/www/html which is my root directory for files

Answer (score 0):

There's a few possible reasons for this issue:

- .htaccess files aren't enabled for your Apache, or they're using a different name.  You should check for an '[AccessFileName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#accessfilename)' option in your config. It should look something like this:

> `AccessFileName .htaccess`

- .htaccess files are enabled, but possibly restricted to disable rewrite rules.  You should look in your config for something along the lines of:

> `AllowOverride None`

If you find that in a place that applies to your website, you can change it to (I think)

> `AllowOverride FileInfo`

to allow rule processing for your site.

- mod_rewrite is somehow disabled.  I don't think this can be the case, because if it were so, I think you'd get an error when Apache tries to parse your .htaccess file.  However, you can confirm this by looking for a line like this in your apache config:

> `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so`

- Something changed in your setup that is somehow causing these rules to fail.  This seems unlikely, but if you have access to the apache conf files, then you can consider turning on [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) to get an idea of what might be happening.

Finally, just supposing you'd rather not use an .htaccess file for some reason (there's definitely some arguments against them), you can put your rewrite rules into a couple different places, depending on your setup.  You can put them in your  or  directives for starters.  The [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for rewrite rules are pretty good, I highly recommend checking them out.